# Pass variable as column name in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
 SET myvar = MONTHNAME(NOW());
 SET @q = CONCAT('Insert into sales', myvar,'customer values (1000, ABC);','Insert into sales', myvar,'customer values (2000, XYZ);');
 PREPARE QUERY from @q;
 EXECUTE QUERY; 
 END //
```

How can we pass variable value as column name into query and concat multiple queries ?

Answer (score 0):

You must have a valid `INSERT INTO` query with placeholders, and run the code as many times as you need.

This can be used in a loop with a cursor and much more:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE mytest()
BEGIN
     SET myvar = MONTHNAME(NOW());
     SET @q = CONCAT('Insert into sales (', myvar,'customer)  values (?, ?);');
     PREPARE QUERY from @q;
     SET @a = 1000;
     SET @b = "ABC";

     EXECUTE QUERY  USING @a, @b;   
     SET @a = 2000;
     SET @b = "XYZ";

     EXECUTE QUERY  USING @a, @b;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE QUERY;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```